# Setting Values in Azure App Configuration from ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-configuration, azure-app-configuration

You can create Azure KeyVault secrets from ARM templates. Can you also create settings in Azure App Configuration from ARM templates in the same way? I can't find any documentation for it if this feature exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't exist yet but we're working on it! It should be coming soon and when it does we'll be sure to put how to do it in [our docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/).

Edit: Support has been added in the 2020-07-01-preview API version. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-resource-manager).

Comment: Anyone else looking for the same info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-resource-manager or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.appconfiguration/2020-07-01-preview/configurationstores/keyvalues looks like support was added in version 2020-07-01-preview

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Azure App Configuration is in preview and free. See the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/) **Reference** on the left of the page. It seems there are no ARM templates for Azure app configuration.

[image]

You also could give feedback about this [on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/issues).

Comment: this is most likely wrong, you can construct appropriate template.

Comment: But there is no template reference for you when you want to construct it.

Comment: Then how you will construct it?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there is already an issue open on this on [github](https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/issues/268)